# Encrypting a value inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, encryption

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME='user'
PASSWORD='1234567890'

printf "$USERNAME\n$PASSWORD" | connect address
```

How do I encrpyt or hide the value for PASSWORD so that one can't open this bash script file and see the username and password?

Comment: `compile shell script` is the key word via google search, might be what you wanted, but personally I have not done that so , that's all I can say about the matter.

Comment: A user has full control over anything that runs on behalf of the user, so there's no way to do this securely.  Either do it insecurely, or give the user `sudo` access to run this script under a different account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want people to open your code you can make a binary from that script:

```
$ sudo apt install shc     # for debian or debian based
$ shc -f script.sh
$ ls -l script.sh.x
```

Check https://tecadmin.net/create-binary-file-from-shell-script/

Comment: I never played around with `shc`, but aside from compiling, I wonder whether the password string would not become visible again if we do a `strings script.sh.x`.

Comment: Same thing here, but tested, and no password leak. Even with `strace -f -s 1000 ./fgile.x`, I don't see any leak